# How to make the inner module use the namespace of outer module

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

First, I define a `vsmoduleUI` and `vsmoduleServer`, and put the different UI and Server in them, base on the `type`.

- ui

  - vsmoduleUI

    - barUI
    - violinUI
    - boxUI
  - others
- server

  - vsmoduleServer

    - barServer
    - violinServer
    - boxServer
  - others

But, it seemed that when I execute the `go`, I can't access the input.
`barServer` is the example, an error occurs because the `red()` in `ifesle` is NULL.
On the other hand, `violinServer`, `boxServer` at least be able to plot because I removed the `if else`, but I still can't access the inputs.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)


vsmoduleUI <- function(type) {
  ns <- NS(type)
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton(ns("go"), "Show control panel, and Generate a reactive plot"),
      shinyjs::hidden(
        div(id = ns("control"),
          get(paste0(type, "UI"))(type)
        )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(ns("plotoutput"))
    )
  )
}

vsmoduleServer <- function(type, userdata, plots) {
  moduleServer(type, function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$go, {
      df <- userdata  # need some process, maybe it can be delete
      plots[[type]] <- get(paste0(type, "Server"))(type, df)
      shinyjs::show("control")
    })
    output$plotoutput <- renderPlot({
      plots[[type]]()
    })

  })
}

barUI <- function(type) {
  ns <- NS(type)
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Main",
      sliderInput(ns("width"), label = "bar width", min = 0.1, max = 0.9, value = 0.9),
      checkboxInput(ns("red"), label = "redbar", value = FALSE)
    ),
    tabPanel("test")
  )
}

barServer <- function(type, df) {
  moduleServer(type, function(input, output, session) {

    # in some bioplot, need some processing
    data_processed <- df[1:10, ]

    # contact with inputs
    width <- reactive({input$width})
    red <- reactive({input$red})

    plot <- reactive({

      p <- data_processed %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg))

      if (red() == FALSE) {
        p <- p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = width())
      } else if (red() == TRUE) {
        p <- p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = width(), aes(fill = "red"))
      }

      return(p)
    })
    return(plot)
  })
}

violinUI <- function(type) {
  ns <- NS(type)
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Main",
      sliderInput(ns("width"), label = "violin width", min = 0.1, max = 0.9, value = 0.1)
    ),
    tabPanel("test")
  )
}

violinServer <- function(type, df) {
  moduleServer(type, function(input, output, session) {

    # in some bioplot, need some processing
    data_processed <- df

    # contact with inputs
    width <- reactive({input$width})

    plot <- reactive({

      p <- data_processed %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) +
        geom_violin(width = width())

      return(p)
    })
    return(plot)
  })
}

boxUI <- function(type) {
  ns <- NS(type)
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Main",
      sliderInput(ns("width"), label = "violin width", min = 0.1, max = 0.9, value = 0.4)
    ),
    tabPanel("test")
  )
}

boxServer <- function(type, df) {
  moduleServer(type, function(input, output, session) {

    # in some bioplot, need some processing
    data_processed <- df

    # contact with inputs
    width <- reactive({input$width})

    plot <- reactive({

      p <- data_processed %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) +
        geom_boxplot(width = width(), fill = "white", color = "black")

      return(p)
    })
    return(plot)
  })
}

ui <- navbarPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  title = "myhub",
  tabPanel("Visualization",
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Bar plot", vsmoduleUI("bar")),
      tabPanel("Violin plot", vsmoduleUI("violin")),
      tabPanel("Box plot", vsmoduleUI("box"))
    )
  ),
  tabPanel("A"),
  tabPanel("B"),
  tabPanel("C"),
  tabPanel("More")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data(mtcars)
  plots <- reactiveValues()
  vsmoduleServer("bar", mtcars, plots)
  vsmoduleServer("violin", mtcars, plots)
  vsmoduleServer("box", mtcars, plots)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

### Findings:

I used `print(session$ns("nsofbarServer"))` found that the namespace is not correct, print is `bar-bar-nsofbarServer`, it repeats.

### Solution:

I think a simple solution is

```
barServer <- function(df) {
  moduleServer(NULL, function(input, output, session) {
    ...
  })
}
```

To avoid additional suffix of the ns.

Comment: You don’t appear to be passing the module id to your module server functions nor calling `moduleServer` correctly. I suggest you start with a simple app based on tutorial examples and incrementally add the functionality you need, checking after each stage that the app works as you expect.

Comment: I use the F12 check the id, I think they're exactly what I want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an input from the initial server, because `input$width` is not known in sub module:

- `get(paste0(type, "Server"))(type, df, input0 = input)`
- *Athing*`Server <- function(type, df,input0)`
- in *Athing*`Server()`, I replace `input$width` by `input0$width`

Try to put  `observeEvent(input$width, { browser();input$width})` inside vsmoduleServer  / moduleServer and inside *Athing*Server /  moduleServer and you could see about "`input$width` is not known in sub module".

Here is my answer with some improvement:

- `ifelse(is.null(input0$width),0.4,input0$width)`
- `if (isTruthy(plots[[type]]) ) {}`
- `input0$width` inside `plot <- reactive({})` (with `ifelse()`)

(But after I written it, I see than I could also backport to your initial source with the todo list ... but without my improvements.)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)


widthBarDefault    <- 0.3
widthViolinDefault <- 0.4
widthBoxDefault    <- 0.5

vsmoduleUI <- function(type) {
  
  
  ns <- NS(type)
  
  tagList(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton(ns("go"), "Show control panel, and Generate a reactive plot"),
        shinyjs::hidden(
          div(id = ns("control"),
              # without output$UI <- renderUI(get(paste0(type, "UI"))(type)) in moduleServer()
              get(paste0(type, "UI"))(type),
              
              # or with output$UI <- renderUI(get(paste0(type, "UI"))(type)) in moduleServer()
              # called twice because of reactive() so I let your  get(paste0(type, "UI"))(type) in vsmoduleUI()
              # uiOutput(ns("UI"))              
          )
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput(ns("plotoutput"))
      )
    )
  )
}

vsmoduleServer <- function(type, userdata, plots) {
  
  
  moduleServer(type, function(input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$go, {
      df <- userdata  # need some process, maybe it can be delete
      
      plots[[type]] <- get(paste0(type, "Server"))( type, df, input0 = input)
      
      shinyjs::show("control")
      
    })
    
    # With uiOutput(ns("UI")) and without get(paste0(type, "UI"))(type) in vsmoduleUI()
    # called twice because of reactive() so I let your  get(paste0(type, "UI"))(type) in vsmoduleUI()
    # output$UI <- renderUI(get(paste0(type, "UI"))(type))    
    
    
    output$plotoutput <- renderPlot({
      
      
      pp <- NULL
      if (isTruthy(plots[[type]]) ) {
        pp <-plots[[type]]()  
      } 
      pp    
      
    })
    
  })
}

barUI <- function( type) {
  
  
  ns = NS(type)
  
  tagList(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Main",
               sliderInput(ns("width"), label = "bar width", min = 0.1, max = 0.9, value = widthBarDefault),
               checkboxInput(ns("red"), label = "redbar", value = FALSE)
      ),
      tabPanel("test")
    )
  )
}



barServer <- function(type, df,input0) {
  moduleServer(type, function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    # in some bioplot, need some processing
    data_processed <- df[1:10, ]
    
    plot <- reactive({
      
      width <- ifelse(is.null(input0$width),widthBarDefault,input0$width)
      red <- ifelse(is.null(input0$red),FALSE,input0$red)
      
      p <- data_processed %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg))
      
      if (red == FALSE) {
        p <- p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = width)
      } else if (red == TRUE) {
        p <- p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = width, aes(fill = "red"))
      }
      return(p)
    })
    return(plot)
  })
}

violinUI <- function(type) {
  
  ns <- NS(type)
  
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Main",
             sliderInput(ns("width"), label = "violin width", min = 0.1, max = 0.9, value = widthViolinDefault)
    ),
    tabPanel("test")
  )
}

violinServer <- function(type, df, input0) {
  moduleServer(type, function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    # in some bioplot, need some processing
    data_processed <- df
    
    plot <- reactive({
      
      width <- ifelse(is.null(input0$width),widthViolinDefault,input0$width)
      
      p <- data_processed %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) +
        geom_violin(width = width)
      
      return(p)
    })
    return(plot)
  })
}

boxUI <- function(type) {
  
  ns <- NS(type)
  
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Main",
             sliderInput(ns("width"), label = "violin width", min = 0.1, max = 0.9, value = widthBoxDefault)
    ),
    tabPanel("test")
  )
}

boxServer <- function(type, df, input0) {
  moduleServer(type, function(input, output, session) {
    
    # in some bioplot, need some processing
    data_processed <- df
    
    plot <- reactive({
      
      width <- ifelse(is.null(input0$width),widthBoxDefault    ,input0$width)
      
      p <- data_processed %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) +
        geom_boxplot(width = width, fill = "white", color = "black")
      
      return(p)
    })
    return(plot)
  })
}

ui <- navbarPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  title = "myhub",
  tabPanel("Visualization",
           tabsetPanel(
             tabPanel("Bar plot", vsmoduleUI("bar")),
             tabPanel("Violin plot", vsmoduleUI("violin")),
             tabPanel("Box plot", vsmoduleUI("box"))
           )
  ),
  tabPanel("A"),
  tabPanel("B"),
  tabPanel("C"),
  tabPanel("More")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  data(mtcars)
  plots <- reactiveValues()
  vsmoduleServer("bar", mtcars, plots)
  vsmoduleServer("violin", mtcars, plots)
  vsmoduleServer("box", mtcars, plots)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is the html to show the good id and sub id of module.

```
<div class="tab-content" data-tabsetid="8981">
    <div class="tab-pane active" data-value="Bar plot" id="tab-8981-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <form class="well" role="complementary">
                    <button id="bar-go" type="button" class="btn btn-default action-button">Show control panel, and Generate a reactive plot</button>
                    <div id="bar-control" class="shinyjs-hide">
                        <div id="bar-UI" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8" role="main">
                <div class="shiny-plot-output html-fill-item" id="bar-plotoutput" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" data-value="Violin plot" id="tab-8981-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <form class="well" role="complementary">
                    <button id="violin-go" type="button" class="btn btn-default action-button">Show control panel, and Generate a reactive plot</button>
                    <div id="violin-control" class="shinyjs-hide">
                        <div id="violin-UI" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8" role="main">
                <div class="shiny-plot-output html-fill-item" id="violin-plotoutput" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" data-value="Box plot" id="tab-8981-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <form class="well" role="complementary">
                    <button id="box-go" type="button" class="btn btn-default action-button">Show control panel, and Generate a reactive plot</button>
                    <div id="box-control" class="shinyjs-hide">
                        <div id="box-UI" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8" role="main">
                <div class="shiny-plot-output html-fill-item" id="box-plotoutput" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found a simple solution